# PE file section names

Tags: windows, portable-executable

According to this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx?ppud=4
we can name the PE sections with custom names.
So in a PE file which its creator has replaced the sections names with his own names,
now if the ".pdata" section for example isn't called ".pdata" anymore so I can't find it by its name.
how can I find the ".pdata"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, according to the [Windows Portable Executable specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) and other source like the ones of Matt Pietrek, sections Names are made for the humans! Typically compilers set "standard" names for specific types of sections content (e.g. ".text" for code, etc..). But, these names are fully ignored by the loader. These sections names can be modified using different methods (using pragma or other tools e.g Peid, etc..). The section of interest (.pdata) is associated the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION directory.

To find the .pdata section (which is BTW an indicator that the image is 64bit) when it has been renamed, all you need to do is to search for the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION directory, and based on its content, retrieve the section it is located in (as you can do for all directories).

Comment: never rely on section names, always access the sections through Directories. Bad guys rename sections in order to evade the eyes of the analysts.